# Strange issue with an update query

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to create a button that updates the field "objectivesdialnumber" changing the number from 1 thru 6 and back to 1. Unfortunately, it is not working and i don't understand why. I have written other queries in this format and they Always work.

```
Private Sub Comando36_Click()

    If [objectivesdialnumber] = 1 Then
     [objectivesdialnumber] = 2
    ElseIf objectivesdialnumber = 2 Then
     objectivesdialnumber = 3
    ElseIf objectivesdialnumber = 3 Then
     objectivesdialnumber = 4
    ElseIf objectivesdialnumber = 4 Then
     objectivesdialnumber = 5
    ElseIf objectivesdialnumber = 5 Then
     objectivesdialnumber = 6
    ElseIf objectivesdialnumber = 6 Then 
     objectivesdialnumber = 1

  End If


End Sub
```

Comment: This is not a query... I understand what you're trying to do, but this is not a query

Comment: Try reading (and writing) `objectivesdialnumber.value`

Comment: I guess it was a stupid mistake.  I was trying to update the underlying table of the value "objectivesdialnumber" but it was not present on my form as an object.  Now i understand better.  Thank for all the help.

Comment: It is often best to give controls a different name to fields / columns, so, for example `if txtobjectivesdialnumber < 6 Then txtobjectivesdialnumber = txtobjectivesdialnumber +1 else ...`

Comment: @Barranka Value is the default for VBA. I have no idea why someone thinks it is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little trick that will spare you all those `if`s.

You can use `Mod` to squeeze all those comparissons:

```vb
txtObjectivesDialNumber = (CInt(txtObjectivesDialNumber) Mod 6) + 1
```

Consider Remou's comment and rename your control

Comment: Great answer, thasnk alot Barranka. I will put that aside to study the syntax and learn that concept.  If you have a chance, i am about to post another question related to this exercise.

Comment: `Mod` (the modulo operator) returns the residual of the division. Examples: `5 Mod 6` returns `5`, `7 Mod 6` returns `1`, `14 Mod 6` returns `2`. The `CInt()`  function converts the value you pass to it to an integer.